# Vector calculations, operators, matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, rotations

1) A plain goes through the origo (0, 0, 0) and it is perpendicular to the vector seen on the picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svu6U.jpg) What is the P matrix, that is projected to the plain, and what is the mirroring T matrix? Their size is 3x3.

2) tan(φ)=1/50. Calculate the 2x2 size matrix of the operator that rotates the plain by φ angle.

3) Let φ angle be the same as in task 2). Calculate the 3x3 size matrix of the linear operator that rotates v vector (seen on the picture ) by φ angle.

If the picture is not seen v is a column vector having (7, 6, 5) with 7 on the top.

I would like to understand how to solve these exercises, so if someone knows the answer, please be kind to explain it to me, because it would be a life saver. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) There is a formula on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Formulas). It says if you can find an orthonormal basis $u_1,u_2$ of the plane, and you make the matrix $A$ whose columns are $u_1$ and $u_2$, then the projection matrix is $P = AA^T$. So if we can find some $u_1$ and $u_2$, you can do the rest using the formula. First, find any old vector in the plane. So just find something whose dot product with $(7,6,5)$ is zero. For example, we can use $(1,-2,1)$. If we take the cross product of this vector with $(7,6,5)$, we will get another vector in the same plane, which is orthogonal to $(1,-2,1)$. So compute $(1,-2,1) \times (7,6,5) = 2(-8,1,10)$. Now just re-scale these vectors so they have length one, and we can use these as $u_1$ and $u_2$:
$$\begin {align*}
u_1 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} (1,-2,1) \\
u_2 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{165}} (-8,1,10)
\end {align*}$$
Your matrix $A$ is then
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{-8}{\sqrt{165}} \\
\frac{-2}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{165}} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{10}{\sqrt{165}} \end{pmatrix} $$
Finally just use the formula $P = AA^T$.

(2) A rotation matrix that rotates counter-clockwise by angle $\phi$ is:
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\phi) & -\sin(\phi) \\ \sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi) \end{pmatrix} $$
See for instance: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)

(3) You need to specify an axis of rotation for $3 \times 3$. I'm not sure what you mean? Do you mean that $v = (7,6,5)$ is the axis of rotation? Or that the axis is orthogonal to this vector? In any case, if you know the correct axis, see [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) for the formula for the $3 \times 3$ rotation matrix.

Comment: The axis is  v=(7,6,5)
Ohh, my God, Thank you so much!! You saved my life, you have no idea how much help this means to me!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the following system of equations 3 times with different
parameters: In the following I calculate the image of the first unit
vector (denoted by x):

$x_{1}+h_{1}=1;$

$
x_{2}+h_{2}=0;
$

$
x_{3}+h_{3}=0;
$

$
x_{1}*h_{1}+x_{2}*h_{2}+x_{3}*h_{3}=0;
$
 (because x and h are perpendicular to each other)

$
-7/5*x_{1}-6/5*x_{2}=x_{3};
$
 (because x must be on the plain)

$
(x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+x_{3}^{2})+(h_{1}^{2}+h_{2}^{2}+h_{3}^{2})=1
$
 (Using the Pythagorean theorem the (length of the x vector)^2+(length
of the m vector)^2 must be 1^2)

Using the same method I want to find the image of the 2nd unit vector.

$
x_{1}+h_{1}=0;$

$
x_{2}+h_{2}=1;$

$x_{3}+h_{3}=0;$

$
x_{1}*h_{1}+x_{2}*h_{2}+x_{3}*h_{3}=0;
$

$
-7/5*x_{1}-6/5*x_{2}=x_{3};
$

$
(x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+x_{3}^{2})+(h_{1}^{2}+h_{2}^{2}+h_{3}^{2})=1
$

And for the image of the 3rd unit vector:

$
x_{1}+h_{1}=0;
$

$
x_{2}+h_{2}=0;
$

$
x_{3}+h_{3}=1;
$

$
x_{1}*h_{1}+x_{2}*h_{2}+x_{3}*h_{3}=0;
$

$
-7/5*x_{1}-6/5*x_{2}=x_{3};
$

$
(x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+x_{3}^{2})+(h_{1}^{2}+h_{2}^{2}+h_{3}^{2})=1
$

Using wolfram alpha I solve these systems, and for the first unit vector its working, but for the others its not! What is the problem? Is it a good way to solve this problem anyway?